# Download de FTP via PHP

Tags: php, ftp

Eu preciso retirar um arquivo de um servidor FTP usando PHP. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Diz que já tentou vários códigos, quais? É importante para nós saber quais para poder ajudar... Já tentou: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php ?

Comment: Se fosse .Net tem o Método WebClient.DownloadFile (URL, SalvarEm)

Comment: O problema é baixar o arquivo do FTP para o seu servidor web, ou do servidor web para o browser? Realmente sem código e mais detalhes não vai dar para responder.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas vamos ver se posso te ajudar. O código a seguir pode ser usado para buscar um arquivo no servidor FTP.

```
$server = "endereco_do_servidor.com.br";
$FTP_HOST = "ftp.exemplo.com";
$FTP_USER = "usuario";
$FTP_PASS = "senha";
$cHandle = ftp_connect($FTP_HOST) or die("O Servidor não pode se conectar ao FTP");
$login_result = ftp_login($cHandle, $FTP_USER, $FTP_PASS) or die("O Servidor não pode logar-se no FTP!");
ftp_get($cHandle, "diretorio_destino/arquivo.ini", "diretorio_origem/arquivo.ini", FTP_BINARY);
```

Mais dúvidas você pode tirar em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ftp.php

Answer (score 0):

talves isso ajude nao esqueca de da permisao na pasta aonde o codigo for rodar

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'teste.pdf'; //nome do arquivo sera salvo 
$server_file = './teste/teste1.pdf'; //aonde esta o arquivo
$ftp_server="204.145.90.95"; 
$ftp_user_name="loginusuario";
$ftp_porta="22";
$ftp_user_pass="senhausuario";

$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_porta);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```